# Sqlite + Jodd is working for inserting data , selecting data but it is not worked for updating data with dboom... how can i achieve with dboom..?

Tags: java, sqlite, jodd

I am able to insert and select data from sqlite with jodd + dboom, but i am not able to update data by dboom as sqlite in not supporting update query alias like

```
update tableName T1 set name ='TEST' where T1.id = 2
```

and dynamic query generation in **dboom** is done with alias. how can I update data. please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If some alias is not working (btw, please write to support how it should look like, so we can fix it), you are totally free not to use it :) Aliases are just tool for writing SQLs in an simple way, they are getting expanded before executed.

So if some alias is not working, just provide the full sql script - or use only aliases that works.

Sorry for that, **DbOom** just tries to simplify writing the queries and do the mapping; but we can add some flags for different dbs... as much as we can :))

Comment: Yes - but please send the query to the support@jodd.org, as maybe we can add some flags to make aliases work for sqlite :)

Comment: I have sent query to jodd support... :-)

Comment: Cool! Meanwhile, try to write the query without aliases that doesnt work, so you can continue :)